# cachedRequestBodyObject is not working in spring cloud gateway custom filter factory

Tags: spring, cloud, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway for my project. I have written one custom filter factory for generating HMAC Signature which requires request payload. I have enabled **readBody(String.class, requestBody -> true)** to true in route definition and from **cachedRequestBody** attribute, I was able to get the request payload in my custom filter with following spring boot **version 2.1.3.RELEASE and spring cloud version 2.1.1.RELEASE**.

**Now after upgrading the spring boot version to 2.3.3.RELEASE and Spring cloud version 2.2.4.RELEASE** same code is not working.

does the readbody predicate not work with latest spring cloud version? any suggestion will be helpful.

Sample of custom filter factory:

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
  
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        HttpMethod method = exchange.getRequest().getMethod();
        String httpVerb = method.name();
        ServerHttpRequest httpRequest = exchange.getRequest();
        String requestPayload = exchange.getAttribute("cachedRequestBodyObject");
       signature = generateSignature(....);
       ServerHttpRequest.Builder builder = httpRequest.mutate().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, signature)
       ServerHttpRequest downStreamRequest= (config.getPath()!=null?builder.path(config.path):builder).build();
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(downStreamRequest).build());
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with spring cloud 2020.0.0 and spring boot 2.4.1 , I am able to get the request payload in my custom filter